# shell scripting - How to zip contents inside a folder without the folder itself?

Tags: bash, shell, zip

I use this current command that archives the folder "folder-root" and all it's content to a file named "site.zip":

```
zip -r site.zip folder-root/*
```

Problem is - I want to zip the contents of the folder and not the folder itself. Notice: I must issue the command from the current directory (ie - can't issue it from inside the folder).

How do I do that?

Answer (score 8):

This should do the job:

```
zip -rj site.zip folder-root/*
```

`zip --help` says:

```
-j   junk (don't record) directory
```

Comment: This will junk any subdirectory inside the directory as well. Not sure if that was wanted.

Answer (score 3):

```
cd folder-root

zip -r ../site.zip *
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has a similiar problem and the answer could work.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597875/how-can-i-build-a-tar-from-stdin

```
zip site.zip `ls -1 folder-root/`
```

This will create the list of files that you want to add into your zip file.

Comment: Unless the files have spaces